# Speed up SQL SELECT in a table with just numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I am going to have data relating the pull force of a block magnet to its three dimentions in an excel table in this form:

```
a/mm | b/mm | c/mm | force/N
---------------------------------
1    | 1    | 1    | 0.11
1    | 1    | 2    | 0.19
1    | 1    | 3    | 0.26
            ...
100  | 80   | 59   | 7425
100  | 80   | 60   | 7542
```

[diagram showing what a, b and c mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sv6E.png)

There is a row for each block magnet whose a, b and c in mm are whole numbers and the ranges are 1-100 for a, 1-80 for b and 1-60 for c. So in total there are 100*80*60=480,000 rows.
I want to make an online calculator where you enter a, b and c and it gives you the force. For this, I want to use a query something like this:

```
SELECT FROM blocks WHERE a=$a AND b=$b AND c=$c LIMIT 1
```

I want to make this query as fast as possible. I would like to know what measures I can take to optimise this search. How should I arrange the data in the SQL table? Should I keep the structure of the table the same as in my Excel sheet? Should I keep the order of the rows as it is? What indexes should I use if any? Should I add a unique ID column to the table? I am open to any suggestions to speed this up.

Note that:

- The data is already nicely sorted by a, b and c
- The table already contains all the data and nothing else will be done to it except displaying it, so we don't have to worry about the speed of UPDATE queries
- a and b are interchangable, so I could delete all the rows where b>a
- Increasing a, b or c will always result in a greater pull force
- I want this calculator to be a part of a website. I use PHP and MySQL.
- If possible, minimising the memory needed to store the table would also be desirable, speed is the priority though
- Please don't suggest answers involving using a formula instead of my table of data. It is a requirement that the data are extracted from the database rather than calculated

Finally, can you estimeate:

- How long such SELECT a query would take with and without optimization?
- How much memory would such a table require?

Answer (score 1):

I would create your table using a, b, c as primary key (since I assume for each triplet of a, b, c there will be no more one record).

The time that will take this select will depend on the rdbms you use but with the primary key it should be very quick. How many peak of queries per minute do you expect to have?

Comment: Therefore you will not have any performance issue trying to access the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the app as fast as possible, store the data in a file and load it into memory into the app or app server (your overall architecture is unclear).  Whatever language you are using to develop the app probably supports a hash-table lookup data structure.

There are good reasons for storing data in a database:  transactional integrity, security mechanisms, backup/restore functionality, replication, complex queries, and more.  Your question doesn't actually suggest the need for any database functionality.  You just want a lookup table for a fixed set of data.

If you really want to store the data in a database, then follow the above procedure.  That is, load it into memory for users to query.

If you have some requirement to use a database (say, your data is changing), then follow my version of USeptim's advice:  create a table with all four columns as primary keys (or alternatively use a secondary index on all four columns).  The database will then do something similar to the first solution.  The difference is the database will (in general) use b-trees to search the data instead of hash functions.

Comment: I want this calculator to be a part of a website. I added this to the question. I use PHP and MySQL. Would you still recommend using something other than a database?